# Iframe video embedded link not working on few android devices

Tags: android, video, iframe, webview

I have an Iframe link :

```
<div style="position:relative; padding-bottom:56.25%; overflow:hidden;"><iframe src="html link here" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;"></iframe></div>
```

I am loading this in a webview. This works fine. But the problem is in some devices it shows only the player, video is not playing. What could be the issue ? Should I add any additional settings for the webview ?

I searched for the issue, I found out that few devices won't support flash player so the video won't play. If this is the issue how can I fix this?

Below is the webview code :

```
mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

    mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl,data_html,"text/html","utf-8",historyUrl);
```

Comment: any logcat hint??

Answer (score 0):

It's 2017, and FlashPlayer was been deprecated by Android since 2012.

I strongly recommend you NOT to look at any other FlashPlayer solution, because the amount of Android device w/o FlashPlayer support will only grow up.

Look for a HTML5 player instead......

Answer (score 0):

To rectify this issue you can use an HTML5 player which has the following structure `<iframe src="https://www.yourDomain.com/embed/VIDEO_ID"></iframe>`